# Jquery autocomplete on hit enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have the following jquery autocomplete:

```
   $(function() {

    $("#my_ac").autocomplete({
        source: [
            {
                label: "/Tom-Hanks",
                value: "Tom Hanks",
                description: "Actor",
                image: "hanks.png"
            },
            {
                label: "/Termionator-2",
                value: "Termionator 2",
                description: "Movie",
                image: "terminator.png"
            }
        ],
        minLength: 1
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var inner_html = '<a href="' + item.label + '"><div class="list_item_container"><div class="image"><img src="' + item.image + '"></div><div class="label">' + item.label + '</div><div class="description">' + item.description + '</div></div></a>';
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append(inner_html)
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

When clicking with the mouse over the generated div (class=list_item_container) it diverts you to "label" link. How can I also divert to the same link on hitting enter?

Comment: You can use select event in autocomple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the select event in autocomplete. Here i assume that your label is the url that u prefer to be redirected from your example.

```
 $("#my_ac").autocomplete({
        select:function(event,ui){
            if(event.keyCode==13){
               window.location = ui.label;   
            }
        },
........
});
```

See more info on autocomplete select event [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)

Comment: I had to replace ui.label with ui.item.label and it worked. Thanks for it.